# Naming booleans

Tags: boolean, naming-conventions, naming

If I only want to check if something is impossible or not (i.e., I will not be using something like `if(possible)`), should I name the boolean `notPossible` and use `if(notPossible)` or should I name it `possible` and use `if(!possible)` instead?

And just to be sure, if I also have to check for whether it is `possible`, I would name the boolean possible and use `if(possible)` along with `else`, right?

Comment: I prefer to keep boolean values in positive-form (isAllowed, possible, authorized), unless there is a good reason to invert the logic.

It helps me keep a consistent convention and I find !possible easier to read that notPossible in a number of cases (!notPossible ?). All that being said, I normally also try to avoid the need/use of boolean flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to err on the side of positivity here and use `possible`.  It means someone can't write some code later that does this...

```
if (!notPossible)
```

Which is unreadable.

Comment: Or you could go one step further and write: `if (!notImpossible)`

Comment: Or if we use Alex's lingo `if (!lacksImpossibility)`

Answer (score 8):

You should probably use `isPossible`.

Negative names for booleans like `notPossible` is a very bad idea. You might end up having to write things like `if (!notPossible)` which makes the code difficult to read. Don't do that.

Comment: Yep, with negative names you'll have to write upside-down code like `if (!(notPossible || notProbable))` instead of the more intuitive `if (possible && probable)`.

Comment: ...or `useCurrentTariff` or  `hasSurcharge` as applicable

Comment: +1. I always try to keep everything in the "positive" even when I'm more interested in the negative. Another example would be using `is_open` instead of `is_closed`... mostly just for consistency in that case, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I like to name booleans with consistent short-verb prefixes such as `is` or `has`, and I'd find a `not` prefix peculiar and tricky to mentally "parse" (so, I suspect, would many readers of the code, whether aware of feeling that way or not;-) -- so, I'd either name the variable `isPossible` (and use `!isPossible`), or just name the variable `isImpossible` (many adjectives have handy antonyms like this, and for a prefix `has` you could use a prefix `lacks` to make an antonym of the whole thing;-).

Answer (score 1):

I generally try to name my flags so that they will read as nicely as possible where they are being used. That means try to name them so that they won't have to be negated where they are used.

I know some folks insist all names be positive, so that people don't get confused between the negations in the name and those in their head. That's probably a good policy for a boolean in a class interface. But if its local to a single source file, and I know all the calls will negate it, I'd much rather see `if (impossible && ...)` than `if (!isPossible && ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever is easier to read in your specifc application. Just be sure you don't end up with "if (!notPossible)".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's considered preferable to avoid using negatives in variable names so that you avoid the double negative of if(!notPossible).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `isPossible`. It just seems to make a lot of sense to use 'is' (or perhaps 'has') whenever you can when naming boolean variables. This is logical because you want to find out if something *is possible*, right?

Comment: What if you want to find out if something is _impossible_?

Comment: You can always put a `!` on a `isPossible`, but you can't take the `not` off of `notPossible`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that negatively named booleans are a bad idea, but sometimes it's possible to reframe the condition in a way that's positive. For example, you might use pathIsBlocked rather than cannotProceed, or rather than isNotAbleToDie you could use isImmortal.

Answer (score 0):

You should name it for exactly what is being stored in it. If you're storing whether it's possible then name it `isPossible`. If you're storing whether it's impossible name it `isImpossible`.

In either case you can use an `else` if you need to check for both cases.

From your description it seems more important to you to check for impossibility so I'd go with  `isImpossible`:

```
if(isImpossible)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```